# Can't initialize Mandrill for Parse on Android

Tags: java, android, parsing, mandrill

For my android app, I want to send a verification email to the user when they sign up. I'm want to do this through Mandrill with Parse backend. I copy and pasted the Mandrill Cloud Module from the Parse docs:

```
var mandrill = require("mandrill");
mandrill.initialize("mandrillAPIKey");

Parse.Cloud.define("myMandrillFunction", function(request, response) {
  mandrill.sendEmail({
    message: {
      text: "Hello World!",
      subject: "Using Cloud Code and Mandrill is great!",
      from_email: "parse@cloudcode.com",
      from_name: "Cloud Code",
      to: [
        {
          email: "you@parse.com",
          name: "Your Name"
        }
      ]
    },
    async: true
  }, {
    success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("Email sent!"); },
    error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
  });
}
```

I replaced the mandrillAPIKEY and email fields with my own. But eclipse says that the "mandrill" string in `require("mandrill");` is an invalid character constant. I think this might have to do with not importing Mandrill properly. How do I fix this?

Comment: This code suppose to be on cloud, this is no way related to android. These are javascript code segments which should be hosted on parse cloud server and your android client interact with it

Comment: I have set up cloud code; how do I integrate/call the function in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to change course. While the comment on your question is correct, parse has options to send a verification email when signing up using a parse user object. I would suggest to turn that on instead.